# AS3 "Error: Return value must be undefined"

Tags: actionscript-3

If I declare a function like this:

```
public function foo():void
{
    // do something
}
```

Sometimes in that function, I might decide to early-out, often with a log message, like so:

```
public function foo():void
{
    if( somethingWentWrong )
    {
        log( "blah blah" );
        return;
    }

    // do something
}
```

where `log()` is essentially a wrapper for `trace()`, with the signature `public function log( msg:String ):void`

To save a bit of space, I might rewrite that check and early-out to this:

```
public function foo():void
{
    if( somethingWentWrong )
        return log( "blah blah" );

    // do something
}
```

This compiles and runs no problem about 99% of the time, *except*, occasionally (when there's a bug in another, unrelated part of the project, or I do a clean), I'll get a compile error in the form of:

```
"Error: Return value must be undefined"
```

And I'll need to re-write it in the long form in order to compile. Once it's compiled, I can then return it to its short form version and everything's happy again.

When this error happens however, it's irritating and I don't like having to rewrite code in introduce 3 lines of redundancy. Any idea on why it's happening (and only very occasionally) and how I can stop it short of writing the long form everywhere? Technically, seeing a `log()` returns `void`, there should be no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your function declaration:

```
public function foo():void
```

suggests that your function shouldn't return anything., so If I were you, I'd just do

```
log( "blah blah" );
return;
```

instead of

```
return log( "blah blah" );
```

The second version is bad, and not only because it doesn't always work, but it also would lead any readers of your code to assume that `log` returns a value, when it actually doesn't.

it makes your code harder to grok.

Answer (score 1):

If a function is to 'return' a value, then the type must be defined.

You have the function defined as 'void', yet you attempt to 'return' a value.

If you intend to return a value, this is the correct way to write your function :

```
// if you want to return a value, you must specify the type
public function foo():String
{
    if( somethingWentWrong )
    {
        // I am assuming that log returns a String
        return log( "blah blah" );
    }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
}
```

Also, if you specify the return type, the function MUST return a value.

Based on what you are trying to do, it seems that you need to also ensure that your log function returns a String. The function signature should be :

```
public function log(msg:String):String
```

and it SHOULD return a String.

Comment: i never wanted to return anything, just to avoid 3 lines of redundant code. seeing as `foo()` and `log()` are both type `void`, technically it should make no difference saying `return log();` - it works, it's just frustrating that it fails at random moments. i get your point though

Comment: I misunderstood that aspect, sorry. I don't think I've ever run into this issue, because if I'm not returning something I wouldn't use `return log("blah blah");`, I'd do it as the other answer suggested to be clear. But yes.. since log is void, technically it should work.